# C# NPOI cannot assign FileInputStream variable to XSSFWorkbook variable

Tags: c#, type-conversion, npoi

So I'm using C# with the NPOI package and trying to assign my file to to a XSSF workbook variable to be read and I'm getting the following error

[image]

here is the relevant code fragment

```
private static XSSFWorkbook workbook;

        //  runs the console, which runs the gogo()
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Console.run2();   
        }

        public void gogo()
        {

            FileInputStream excelFile;
            try
            {
                //  get the file and assign it to excelFile
                excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FileName.getFile()));

                //  open up the excelfile workbook
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

                //  get the # of sheets in the workbook for iterator
                this.lastSheet = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XSSFWorkbook` ctor accepts `Stream` as its argument. However, `FileInputStream` does not extend `Stream` (nor is it implicitly convertible). One way to solve your issue is to use `FileStream` instead of `FileInputStream`. For example:

```
FileStream excelFile = File.OpenRead(FileName.getFile());
```